# QUnit is only running the first test

Tags: unit-testing, qunit

I can't get QUnit to run any test after the first. To be sure I wasn't doing something weird, I pared down the code to be as basic as possible.

```
test("A", function () {
    ok(true, "Test A");
});
test("B", function () {
    ok(true, "Test B");
});
```

Test A is the only one that runs. No errors thrown or anything else.

My HTML file looks like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Test title</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.10.0.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div id="qunit"></div>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.10.0.js"></script>
   <script src="tests.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I copy pasted everything into jsfiddle and it worked. Could this have something to do with running it locally?

Comment: Tested running through a local Apache server rather than `file://` and found that it worked. Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Comment: If you're having this problem, tell the QUnit people that the UI is dumb! https://github.com/jquery/qunit/issues/528

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Found the problem. It was this!

`qunit.html?testNumber=1`

I guess at some point I hit `rerun` and it ignored the other tests!

This other question deserves credit for pointing me in the right direction. [QUnit Won't Run Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040167/qunit-wont-run-tests)

Comment: where is qunit.html?testNumber=1? in which file. I run same problem.

Comment: @user84592 In the URL. Just got caught with that. Thanks +1

Comment: Thank dude,  I did the exact same thing by accident,  could not figure out one only one test was running, event though multiple ones were specified.

Answer (score 0):

very similar to Mims H. Wright's answer.

I also hit "rerun" on a failing test, and it appended the testId to my url, which I didnt notice.

```
tests.html?testId=fb134038
```